# getting "segmentation fault" error while updating wordpress version using wp-cli

Tags: wordpress, wp-cli

I am trying to update WordPress using wp-cli but after running the command getting "Segmentation fault" error.

Please suggest a solution.

following is the command that I used,

```
wp core update
```

after running the above command I get an error "Segmentation fault"

My PHP version is PHP 5.6.30 and Operating System is: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)

Comment: You're going to have to add more detail to get a decent answer. Do you have logs you could post?

Comment: Hi @Haem, I took a snapshot of my terminal.Please find the link for the snapshot.
https://prnt.sc/hzgh17

Comment: [Do not post screenshots of code or error messages, copy and paste them to your question instead](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). I'm not sure that what little the screenshot is showing is likely to help either way.